# Accessing data from text file with double dictionary in it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file which has data like

```
{"0":{"Name":"ABC","Age":30,"City":"XYZ"},"1":{"Name":"LMN","Age":20,"City":"PQR"}}
```

I want to import this text file and read the dictionary.

```
file = open('text_file.txt','r')

dictn = eval(file.read())

print(dictn)
```

this code. But not getting correct result.

Can anyone tell me how to read this sort of file which has double dictionary in it using Python.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do **not** use `eval`...

Comment: just removing eval will solve the problem ?

Comment: @Anirudha.I: no, but `eval` is unsafe: here you make yourself vulnerable to code injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a JSON file, you can simply use:

```
import json

with open('text_file.txt','r') as file:
    dictn = json.load(file)
print(dictn)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a JSON Object and you can read it with:

```
import json

data = json.load(open('text_file.txt', 'r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, also, use `literal_eval` from `ast` module instead of using `eval` which is not safe.

This is an example of how you can do it:

```
from ast import literal_eval as le

with open("new_data", 'r') as fp:
    data = le(fp.read())

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'Age': 30, 'City': 'XYZ', 'Name': 'ABC'}, '1': {'Age': 20, 'City': 'PQR', 'Name': 'LMN'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `yaml` library from `pyyaml`:

import yaml

```
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    dictn = f.read()
    print(dictn)
    print(type(dictn))
    result = yaml.load(dictn)
    print(result)
    print(type(result))
```